# Getting a specific part of a website with Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: beautifulsoup

I got the basics down of finding stuff with Beautiful Soup 4. However right now I am stuck with a specific problem.I want to scrape the "2DKT94P" from the data-oid of the below code:

```
<div class="js-object   listitem_wrap " data-estateid="45784882" data-oid="2DKT94P">
<div class="listitem relative js-listitem ">
```

Any pointers on how I might do this? I would also appreciate a pointer for an advanced tutorial that covers this, and/or a link on where I would have been able to find this in the official documentation because I failed to recognize the correct part...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should locate the div tag using class attribute then get it's `data-oid` attribute

```
div = soup.find("div", class_="js-object")

oid = div['data-oid']
```

Comment: When I try to print oid or oid.text I receive the following: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable Any ideas?

Comment: @user2252633 check my update, I think it's the whitespace cause the problem

Answer (score 1):

If your data is well formated you can do this via this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """
<div class="js-object   listitem_wrap " data-estateid="45784882" data-
oid="2DKT94P">
<div class="listitem relative js-listitem ">2DKT94P DIV</div>
</div>
<div>other div</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")
RandomDIV = soup.find(attrs= {"data-oid":"2DKT94P"})
print (RandomDIV.get_text().strip())
```

Outputs:

> 2DKT94P DIV

Find more info about `find` or `find_all` with attributes [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments).

Or via `select`:

```
RandomDIV = soup.select("div[data-oid='2DKT94P']")
print (RandomDIV[0].get_text().strip())
```

Find more about [select](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

**EDIT:**

Totally misunderstood the question. If you want to search only for `data-oid` you can do like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")
RandomDIV = soup.find_all(lambda tag: [t for t in tag.attrs if 
t  == 'data-oid'])
for div in RandomDIV:
    #data-oid
    print(div["data-oid"])
    #text
    print (div.text.strip())
```

Learn more [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs)).

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! However, the content of data-oid is always different, most probably 20 different data-oid's on one page. This ID is what I want to find and save as a string to a list.

Comment: Thank you very much! I accepted the other answer as it was simple and to the point.